# Golang channels issue

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I have a simple example with channels: https://play.golang.org/p/eLcpzXeCHms

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func execute(trueChan chan<- bool, lowerRange int32, upperRange int32) {
    for lowerRange <= upperRange {
        fmt.Printf("\nhandling number %v", lowerRange)
        if lowerRange%2 == 0 {
            go func() {
                trueChan <- true
            }()
        }
        lowerRange++
    }
    close(trueChan)
}

func main() {
    counter := 0

    trueChan := make(chan bool)

    execute(trueChan, 5, 25)

    for {
        if _, ok := <-trueChan; ok {
            counter++
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n%v", counter)
}
```

The first problem:  i get an error message sometimes...

```
handling number 5
handling number 6
handling number 7
handling number 8
handling number 9
handling number 10
handling number 11
handling number 12
handling number 13
handling number 14
handling number 15
handling number 16
handling number 17
handling number 18
handling number 19
handling number 20
handling number 21
handling number 22
handling number 23
handling number 24
handling number 25
0
panic: send on closed channel
```

And the second problem - my counter is always 0.

Can someone give me a hint, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

1. Creates an unbuffered channel `trueChan`.
2. Creates 10 goroutines, each of which will attempts to write to `trueChan`, which will block until something reads from it.
3. Closes `trueChan`, then returns to `main()`
4. `main()` prints `0` because it has not read anything from the goroutines yet
5. Meanwhile, because `trueChan` was closed in step 3, before the goroutines are done using it, the first goroutine to try to write to the channel panics

At minimum, you should not be closing `trueChan` until you know all goroutines are done with it. In practice, you're closing it before they even *begin* to use it.

A `sync.WaitGroup` might be one way to do that, but it's not obvious how to do that in your code, since I'm not entirely sure of your goal. This code looks like a simple exercise, and not a real-world example.  If you can explain your goal, I can probably offer a more specific recommendation.

Comment: you are right, it's a simple exerciese, not a real-world example. I just want to learn how to use channels/waitGroups etc. I already tried to solve the problem with a WaitGroup, but was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

Your first and sencond problem are in the same root:
You close the channel in **main routine**,the program close the channel, exit the program before your routine sending data to channel
You have to usually close the channel in defer of go routine which using that chanel. For example, and the fix for yout code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func execute(trueChan chan<- bool, lowerRange int32, upperRange int32) {
    go func() {
        defer func(){
            close (trueChan)
        }()
        for lowerRange <= upperRange {
            fmt.Printf("\n handling number %v", lowerRange)
            if lowerRange%2 == 0 {
                trueChan <- true
            }
            lowerRange++
        }

    }()
}

func main() {
    counter := 0

    trueChan := make(chan bool)

    execute(trueChan, 5, 25)

    for _ = range trueChan{ // For small improvement here. Ref as below 
            counter++
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n%v", counter)
}
```

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4